# Flattening nested callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, callback

Here is a callback (slightly modified/simplified for the purposes of this question) I have written to process some object data.

```
  function (err, data) {
    var rv;
    if (data && data.result instanceof Array) {
      rv = data.result.map(function (value) {
        if (value && value.track_contributions instanceof Array) {
          return value.track_contributions.map(function (innerValue) {
            if (innerValue && innerValue.track) {
              return innerValue.track.mid;
            }
          });
        }
      });
      // flatten nested arrays
      rv = [].concat.apply([], rv);
    }
    console.log(rv);
  };
```

Here's what the object that I'm processing looks like:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "type": "/music/artist",
      "track_contributions": [
        {
          "track": {
            "mid": "/m/015rm3l"
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "mid": "/m/0nm2km"
          }
        },
        {
          "track": {
            "mid": "/m/010ksbq"
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I want a return value from my callback that looks like this:

```
[ '/m/015rm3l',
  '/m/0nm2km',
  '/m/010ksbq',
  ...
]
```

My code works just fine, but I feel like all that nesting is a code smell.

How should I go about making this type of code flatter, more readable and maintainable, and all that great stuff? Promises? Some lodash type utility? Something else? All of the above?

Comment: This approach will result in a lot of `undefined` values if the conditions in the `map` functions are not true. Because in those cases nothing is returned instead.

Comment: @Amberlamps That's correct. My code expects that. But yes, worth noting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version that I think is simpler to understand and maintain with no duplicated code because it uses a generic traversal with a callback to add the specifics of your data structure:

```
function process(err, data) {
    var rv = [];
    function doObject(obj, key, callback) {
        if (obj[key] && obj[key] instanceof Array) {
            obj[key].forEach(function(value) {
                callback(value);
            });
        }
    }
    doObject(data, "result", function(result) {
        doObject(result, "track_contributions", function(item) {
            if (item.track && item.track.mid) {
                rv.push(item.track.mid);
            }
        });

    });
    console.log(rv);
}
```

---

Without changing the base algorithm you are using, you could initialize `rv` and just push the results directly into `rv` rather than making sub-arrays that then have to be flattened.

```
function process(err, data) {
    var rv = [];
    if (data && data.result instanceof Array) {
        data.result.forEach(function(value) {
            if (value && value.track_contributions instanceof Array) {
                value.track_contributions.forEach(function(innerValue) {
                    if (innerValue && innerValue.track) {
                        rv.push(innerValue.track.mid);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    console.log(rv);
}
```

---

Because the property names that you're looking for at each level are different, it's not as efficient or easy to use recursion to avoid the repeated code (though that is an option).

Here's a two level recursive algorithm, though I don't think the added complexity is actually worth it.  If you were going more than 2 levels deep or an arbitrary number of levels it might make more sense:

```
function process(err, data) {
    var rv = [];
    function doArray(item, key1, key2) {
        if (item && item[key1] instanceofArray) {
            item[key1].forEach(function(value) {
                if (key2) {
                    doArray(value, key2);
                } else if (value && value.track.mid) {
                    rv.push(value.track.mid);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    doArray(data, "result", "track_contributions");
    console.log(rv);
}
```

Comment: Added a recursive algorithm.

Comment: That is an interesting solution, but this is neither more readable nor more maintainable. Additionallly, recursion is completely unneccessary here.

Comment: @Amberlamps - See the notes about the recursive solution in my answer.  IMO, my first solution is simpler to understand than the OP's (pushing results directly into the results array rather than producing nested arrays) and is slightly shorter.  Not a big gain, but there isn't a lot else to do with this code so that's what I could find.

Comment: @Trott - Added the first option in my answer which is a more generic traversal with callbacks that I think is easier to maintain and understand and extend or reuse in other contexts if ever desired.

Answer (score 1):

This approach will get you the desired output:

```
function getArray(err, data) {

  var rv;

  function mapArray(obj, array, callback) {
    if (obj && obj[array] instanceof Array) {
      return obj[array].map(callback);
    }
  }

  function getValue(value) {
    return mapArray(value, 'track_contributions', getInnerValue);
  }

  function getInnerValue(innerValue) {
    return innerValue.track && innerValue.track.mid;
  }

  rv = [].concat.apply([], mapArray(data, 'result', getValue));

  console.log(rv);

};

getArray(null, data);
```

The key is to split every function into its desired purpose and reuse every function that repeats itself.

The mapping for instance is done twice. So lets write a generic function `mapArray` for that. It expects an `obj`, the name of the array attribute `array` and a callback.

For the outer function in your example we have `mapArray(data, 'result', getValue)` and for the inner function it is `mapArray(value, 'track_contributions', getInnerValue)`.

Inside the `getValue` function we define the outer function and `getInnerValues` defines the inner function.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing the traversal of the data structure with the domain logic to be applied on its nodes, hence the code smell. It's better to decouple both aspects, having a generic traversal algorithm provided with a domain function (in your current case a collector).

For instance:

```
  function traverse(source, collector) {
    for(var property in source) {
      var value = source[property];
      if (value instanceof Array) {
        for(var ii=0; ii<value.length; ii++) {
          arguments.callee(value[ii], collector);
        }
      } else if (value instanceof Object){
          arguments.callee(value, collector);
      } else {
          collector(property, value);
      }
    }
  }

  var values=[];
  traverse(source, function(property, value) {
    if (property == "mid") {
        values.push(value);
    }
  });
  document.write(values.join(", "));
```

The traversal algorithm could be more complicated, depending on the rules constraining your original data structure; make sure to keep it minimal in the end (i.e. do not write code you won't be using).

Comment: Won't this just collect all `mid` properties, no matter where they are in the data structure?  And, won't this also iterate any enumerable properties on the arrays?  And, won't this also fail in `strict` mode?

Comment: 1) Yes, they will collect all "mid" properties, because I was under the impression that this was the OP's goal and wanted to keep the code minimal. One could easily change the traversal algorithm, for instance having it collecting and passing the full property path (and not only the last bit), if this is a requirement.

Comment: As for your other remarks: "for in" will iterate over enumerable properties, which is what we want here. The code is indeed not compatible with "strict mode", because it uses arguments.callee. In both cases, if your requirements are different, then do not hesitate to adjust the code to meet them! To remove the arguments.callee, you can either directly refer to the named property associated with the function declaration (slightly less clean, since it accesses an external free variable name), or change the function into a named function expression (with the usual browser caveat).